# A right way to use uuid as key in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was fetching videos from an API and there were duplicates. So, I applied uuid to generate a key for each - `key={uuid()}` - until realizing that I was generating a new key for every render.

Below is my fix, but I am not quite sure if it's really solving the issue.

```
export default function VideoList({ videos, observedElement }) {
  const location = useLocation();

  const videoList = videos.map((video, index) => {
    video.uuid = uuid();

    return (
      <Link
        to={`/videos/${video.id.videoId}`}
        state={{ backgroundLocation: location }}
        key={video.uuid}
      >
        <VideoListEntry info={video} ref={observedElement} />
      </Link>
    );

  return <div>{videoList}</div>
}
```

Edit: I know that using an id from db or creating a combination within the given data is more preferable. But I just want to know if there is a way to generate a stable key with uuid.

Comment: if there is something unique to each video use it? or if there is a combination of fields that make it unique?

Comment: Whats the urgent to use UUID? You actually have a `video.id.videoId` for this

Comment: @cmgchess I know that would be the best case scenario, but I want to figure out if there is a way to generate a lasting(or stable) key with uuid.

Comment: @DennisVash there are duplicates in the list I am fetching from. The video.id.videoId is not unique too.

Comment: You’re generating a new uuid for each element every time the map  runs. If you want it to be stable across renders you need to assign the ids once, outside the map function.

Comment: What's the point of an id if it's not unique? So even if you deduped your dataset there would still be objects with duplicate ids?

Comment: I don’t think there’s any problem in the way you have implemented. Why would you want to have fixed ids? This would work fine. If you still care, you can define a fix list of UUIDs and provide them as keys. Also, no need to attach the uuid to video object. You can directly provide the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way would be to get the id directly from wherever you are getting the videos.

The next one, would be to generate them the moment you receive them from the remote location (*assuming you get them from an API*). So, right after getting them, enrich them with the uuid, and then store them to the state/store.

The third solution, would be to use a `useEffect` inside your component, that would only generate ids when the video property is altered.

```js
export default function VideoList({
  videos = [],
  observedElement
}) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [videosWithId, setVideosWithId] = useState(videos);

  useEffect(() => {
    const withId = videos.map(video => ({
      ...video,
      uuid: uuid()
    }))
    setVideosWithId(withId);
  }, [videos]);

  // use videosWithId from below this point, instead of the videos prop
  ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

define a variable that holds the value of uuid like this and use it I think it will work for you

```
export default function VideoList({ videos, observedElement }) {
  const location = useLocation();

  const videoList = videos.map((video, index) => {
    let uuid = uuid()
    video.uuid = uuid 

    return (
      <Link
        to={`/videos/${video.id.videoId}`}
        state={{ backgroundLocation: location }}
        key={uuid}
      >
        <VideoListEntry info={video} ref={observedElement} />
      </Link>
    );

  return <div>{videoList}</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion does not work. I am watching React devtool to see if the keys change whenever a chunk of videos gets added to the previous videos, and all the keys change.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function VideoList({ videos, observedElement }) {
  const location = useLocation();

  videos.forEach(video => video.uuid = uuid()); // loop through the list and generate the id
  
  const videoList = videos.map((video, index) => {
    return (
      <Link
        to={`/videos/${video.id.videoId}`}
        state={{ backgroundLocation: location }}
        key={video.uuid}
      >
        <VideoListEntry info={video} ref={observedElement} />
      </Link>
    );

  return <div>{videoList}</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't prevent react from generating new ids for every video for each render.

Comment: Yeah, the accepted answer is the way to go, didn't thought about that, but generally you'd store it in a state either locally or in context